# Using validation in asp Multiview

Tags: asp.net, validation, multiview

I'm trying to use validation in a page consisting of two views. The first view works, but not the second. The Validationsummary error is never displayed and it swollows whatever I feed to it, even very incorrect data. So.. I've missed something for sure, or is it impossible to have this combination? Do I need to catch the validation myself to prevent incorrect data and then how do I do that?
Regards

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultfocus="txtCardID">
<div>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
            ValidationGroup="action" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="False" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCardID" runat="server">
        <asp:MultiView ID="Mview" runat="server">
        <asp:View runat="server" ID="card">
    .......
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Columns="6" MaxLength="6" 
                        ValidationGroup="action"></asp:TextBox> 
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSum" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Error!" Text="*"     ValidationGroup="action" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtAmount" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="rngvSum" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Error!" Text="*" 
                        ValidationGroup="action" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" Display="Dynamic" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True" MaximumValue="99999" MinimumValue="1" Type="Currency"></asp:RangeValidator>
  .......
              <asp:view runat="server" ID="purchase">
  .......
                      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSum" runat="server" Columns="6" MaxLength="6" 
                        ToolTip="Total sum" ValidationGroup="action" /> 
                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Another Error!" Text="*" ValidationGroup="action" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtSum" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Error again!" Text="*" 
                        ValidationGroup="action" ControlToValidate="txtSum" Display="Dynamic" 
                        SetFocusOnError="True" MaximumValue="99999" MinimumValue="1" Type="Currency"></asp:RangeValidator>
                        </td>
```

Comment: have you checked Validation Group ? and did you place validation summery on both Views ?

Comment: Yes, validationgroup is "action" on both txtFields. No, I read that I need to put the ValidationSummary outside the views so its the first control on the page, before the two different views

Comment: Have you set the validation group on the button that is causing the postback in the second view?